# Create multiple plots using pyplot and gridspec on separate 'windows'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to plot two things simultaneously. I do not want them on the same plot. Following is the code for first plot:

```
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 20)
gs1.update(left=0.12, right=.94, wspace=0.12)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7:, 0:6])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7, 7:13], sharey = ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7, 14:20], sharey = ax1)
ax1.set_ylim(-2750,-2650)
ax1.plot(r_array_u, sum_dist, c = 'b', marker= '>')
ax2.plot(r_array_u, sum_dist_perp1, c = 'r', marker= '>')
ax3.plot(r_array_u, sum_dist_perp2, c = 'r', marker= '>')
```

The second plot is run by the following code:

```
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(8, 20)
gs1.update(left=0.12, right=.94, wspace=0.12)
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7:, 0:6])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7, 7:13], sharey = ax1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:7, 14:20], sharey = ax1)
ax1.set_ylim(-2750,-2650)
ax1.plot(r_array, sum_dist5, c = 'b', marker= '>')
ax2.plot(r_array, sum_dist6, c = 'r', marker= '>')
ax3.plot(r_array, sum_dist7, c = 'r', marker= '>')
```

How can I plot these plots on two separate 'windows' (although I use ubuntu), in a single run of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new figure before doing the plot.

```
plt.figure()
```

If you want to go back, you can do it like this:

```
plt.figure()   # figure 1
plt.plot(stuff)

plt.figure()   # figure 2
plt.scatter(more_stuff_x, more_stuff_y)

# Wait, I want to add something to the first:
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(new_stuff)

plt.show()
```